# Select element and its descendants

Tags: xpath, jcr

I'm trying to select an folder and its descendants from a JCR with XPath. I can select the folder easily enough:

```
//content/documents/folder-name
```

I can select its descendants too:

```
//content/documents/folder-name//*
```

However, I can't figure out how to get both. I've tried several things. These select nothing:

```
//content/documents/folder-name | //content/documents/folder-name//*
//content/documents/folder-name(. | *)
//content/documents/folder-name/(. | *)
//content/documents/folder-name/descendant-or-self
//content/documents/folder-name/descendant-or-self::node()
```

These both throw a `javax.jcr.query.InvalidQueryException`:

```
//content/documents/folder-name[. | *]
//content/documents/folder-name/[. | *]
```

Obviously I'm terrible at XPath. Please help.

Edit: I was using the `//` prefix because I didn't realize I could use `/jcr:root/content` instead. I have the same problem with that, however.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine two XPaths using the union operator:

```
xpath1 | xpath2
```

However, your first XPath,

```
//content/documents/folder-name
```

does select the `folder-name` element(s), which includes the descendants of the element.

If you want the `folder-name` elements to be first in a list, followed by their descendants, you could combine as follows:

```
//content/documents/folder-name | //content/documents/folder-name//*
```

Comment: `/jcr:root/content/documents/folder-name | /jcr:root/content/documents/folder-name/*` selects nothing. Likewise for `//content/documents/folder-name | //content/documents/folder-name//*`. `//content/documents/folder-name` does not include descendants.

Comment: Maybe you'd better post sample XML and the exact results you're expecting in order for us to know what you're trying to do.  The XPaths in your comment now include namespace prefixes, and that's another possible source of potential issues that we cannot diagnose without seeing your XML.

Comment: I'd like to, but it's a HUGE file with NDA stuff in it. I'll try to get something close when I have a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

`//content/documents/folder-name/descendant-or-self::node()` looks correct to me (without seeing your XML input), though `//content/documents/folder-name/descendant-or-self::*` is probably better.

Certainly if `//content/documents/folder-name` selects something then ``//content/documents/folder-name/descendant-or-self::*` should also select something.

In XPath 2.0 you can do `//content/documents/folder-name/(.|descendant::*)` but although it's shorter, it seems clumsier to me than using the descendant-or-self axis.